# Kivy Markup with StringProperty()

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am creating a basic TCP client which I can use at work to test bits of equipment through the AK protocol. The program tests the TCP connection first, and then takes three parameters:

- The text that you want to send.
- The number of times you want to send it.
- The frequency at which you want to send it.

There is an output TextInput which shows sent and received text, along with timestamps. I have a function which builds up this string then sets the StringProperty to this to update the GUI.

I have the basics down, but I would like to format the output so it is easier to read (ie. making transmit red, and receive green, or putting the timestamp in italics).

Here is the relevant bit of code where I have tried to bold a bit of text:

```py
class AkInput(Screen):

    num = 0
    ak_op = StringProperty()

    def send_ak(self,ak_text,ak_repeat_num,dt):
        app = App.get_running_app()
        sock_con = g.socket_connection
        rtn_val = tcp.send_message(ak_text,sock_con)
        ak_return = rtn_val[0]
        # Remove last 4 digits from fractional seconds
        send_time = rtn_val[1][:-4]
        recv_time = rtn_val[2][:-4]
        ak_output = send_time + "    [b]Tx[/b]    " + ak_text + "\n" + recv_time + "    Rx    " + ak_return + "\n"
        self.ak_op = self.ak_op + str(ak_output)
        self.ak_loop += 1
        # Stop calling send_message() when number of times has been reached
        if self.ak_loop >= ak_repeat_num:
            self.event.cancel()
```

The relevant part of my Kivy file looks like this:

```
<AkInput>:
    FloatLayout:

        TextInput:
            id: ak_output
            markup:True
            multiline:True
            readonly:True
            font_size: 14
            size_hint: 0.9, 0.45
            pos_hint: {'x':0.05, 'y':0.2}
            text: root.ak_op
```

I thought maybe it was something to do with how I have built the string up so I tried setting the TextInput to something simple like "[b]Hello World[/b]", but the markup still did not work and it just appeared as how I typed it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't think `markup` is supported by `TextInput`, but is in  `Label`.

Comment: Ah right! That looks like what it is. Now I just need to figure out a way of making a suitable label format. Thanks for your help!